# How to call the web service form code behind

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, c#-4.0

I have one web service which I want to call from my code behind page not from my source code. I google the topic but in most of the links I found that they called the web service from the source code by using ajax post

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "webservice.asmx/webservice",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });
```

But I don't want to use this approach I simply want to call the webservice from my code behing page. Any help?

Comment: Any suggestions please...??

Comment: Generate the web service client if it's an ASMX, I'd assume you have a WSDL available, wsdl.exe can be used to generate the client, or you can use HttpClient to create a request to that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Web Reference to your project.

Here is a step by step guide on how to consume a web service :

[C#.Net How To: Consume a Web Service in C#.Net Visual Studio 2010](http://www.csharptutorial.in/37/csharp-net-how-to-consume-a-web-service-in-csharp-net-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code block.

```
public string CallWebMethod(string url, Dictionary<string, string> dicParameters)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] requestData = this.CreateHttpRequestData(dicParameters); 
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpRequest.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
        httpRequest.Timeout = 30000;
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
        String response = String.Empty;

        httpRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream baseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(baseStream);
        response = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseStreamReader.Close();

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

private byte[] CreateHttpRequestData(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
{
    StringBuilder sbParameters = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string param in dic.Keys)
    {
        sbParameters.Append(param);//key => parameter name
        sbParameters.Append('=');
        sbParameters.Append(dic[param]);//key value
        sbParameters.Append('&');
    }
    sbParameters.Remove(sbParameters.Length - 1, 1);

    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

    return encoding.GetBytes(sbParameters.ToString());

}
```